# CSS Keep on-hover item open until another item is hovered on

Tags: css, onhover

Is it possible using only CSS to expand an item when a user hovers on an item, and keep it this way until the user hovers on another item?

I have tried transitions, which will expand and remain open or expand and close, but not expand, wait for another action, and then re-close the item.

```
<html>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</html>

#menu {
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 10px;
    background: #eee;
}

#menu li{
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 10px;
    transition:0s 180s;
}

#menu li:hover {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 12px;
    transition:0s;
}

#menu ul:hover {
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 12px;
    transition:0s;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible with merely CSS Why not use jQuery?

Comment: Its a work thing, i cant edit the html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:hover` pseudo class applies for the duration that a pointer is over an element.

If the user leaves the element, they aren't hovering it anymore. So ,the short answer is **no**.

You could use animations to delay the effect. Instead of actually keeping the element visible, even after the cursor leaves, you could put an animation on it that just adds a delay before it closes.

If you applied an animation to both the hover state, and the normal state, that may help. But, if your hover effect is changing something from `display:none` to `display:block`, you won't get any help since `display` is not animatable. You'd need to use something like `visibility` or `height`.